# How to add the date value in UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

From today date to 5 years how to add the values in UIPickerView

Comment: refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611431/how-to-populate-uipicker-with-current-day-of-week-date

Comment: Do you mean by UIDatePicker or UIPickerView?

Answer (score 2):

Why should you use UIPickerView, Why not UIDatePicker?

You can set the `MinimumDate` and `MaximumDate` in UIDatePicker. You should code as,

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:5];
    NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
    [comps release];
    [calendar release];
    [datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
    [datePicker setMinimumDate:currentDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIDatePickerView. And set value if this date picker as Start and End date..
UIDatePicker has a property of Start and End Date Values..

maximumDate

minimumDate

These two property helps you..